# View selector return value when debugging in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I am running through an iPhone development tutorial and I have a weird bug that I am investigating using the debugger.  I have the following code that checks to see if a object is in bounds.  I am trying to see what the value of ball.center.x is at a certain point, but because center is a property accessor selector, I don't get the value when I hover over it in the Xcode debugger.

```
if (ball.center.x > self.view.bounds.size.width || ball.center.x < 0) {
    ballVelocity.x = -ballVelocity.x;
}
```

Is there a way to do this?  I think I must just be missing something.  I suppose I could update the code to assign the value to a variable that I could then watch in the debugger, but that seems like a sloppy work around to a common problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and then there's also the venerable quick and dirty:

```
if (ball.center.x > self.view.bounds.size.width || ball.center.x < 0) {
    NSLog(@"ball center: %d",ball.center.x);
    ballVelocity.x = -ballVelocity.x;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the log code NSLog(@"ball center Y: %f", ball.center.y); to get the values. Thanks for the tip. It seems there is no shortcut for viewing these values in the debugger, but logging works easily enough.

Comment: sometimes quick and dirty does the job

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume center is an CGPoint.

In addition to the Xcode GUI debugger, there's also a gdb prompt available when you're debugging. Try this:

```
p* ball
```

or

```
p ball.center
```

Comment: p* ball did enumerate all the properties for the ball instance, but still did not display the center CGPoint property.  p ball.center gave an error: "there is no member named center".  I ended up going with the NSLog suggestion.  However, I did not know about GDB, so this was a helpful suggestion.  I need to read more about it, but it seems like a valuable tool.

Comment: gdb is good stuff. If you post a bit more of your code (specifically the types of these things) I'll tell you how to access it in gdb.

Comment: Is gdb aware of property getters? If not, that might be the issue. You could try invoking the getter yourself: `po [ball center]`.

Comment: `po`, if you don't know, prints a representation of an object by sending `-description` (or is it `-debugDescription`?) to the object and printing the result.

Comment: I believe it's -debugDescription if it exists, falling back to -description if not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this **gdb** command:

```
p (CGPoint)[ball center]
```

I use this trick with UIView.frame, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is even easier way to do this than usingthe gdb console. From main menu choose:

```
Run -> Variables View -> View in expression window
```

And in the expression window's text field type:

```
(CGPoint)[ball center]
```

The main problem with expression windows showing the 'out of scope' error message is it almost never knows the return type of a function (or method), so it does not know how to present the returned variable. Apple gives us a clue what to do is such cases [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/220-Viewing_Variables_and_Memory/variables_and_memory.html) under the 'Tips on using the Expressions window'.